# Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires at least jQuery v1.9.1 but less than v4.0.0

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have this in my console any suggestion how to solve it?

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires at least jQuery v1.9.1 but less than v4.0.0

Note I am using Bootstrap 4.4.1 and Jquery 3.4.1

Comment: If you're seeing that error then it's likely that you've accidentally loaded another, lower, version of jQuery which has overridden the 3.4.1 instance. You need to remove it.

Comment: Do you happen to put the jQuery include after the bootstrap one?

Comment: Open your page, open the console, enter `jQuery.fn.jquery` - what does it say?

Comment: @epascarello  here how I include the scripts and link for both jquery and bootstrab


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: @freedomn-m it says

jQuery.fn.jquery
"3.4.1"

Comment: @Rory McCrossan How to check that I am loading another one?

Comment: Can you share demo link

Comment: Edit your bootstrap.js / bootstrap.min.js add add a similar: `console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery)` as the very first line and what does that say?  (normally we don't edit libraries, but in this case it's temporary) (this also assumes you have a local copy and not loading from CDN).

Comment: @vadivel a I am working on it locally

Comment: I see that my project loads a lot of scripts and has many jquery files.

Answer (score 0):

Type $.fn.jquery in your console and tell us what numbers it says. You probably have a second version running somewhere.